# How to get Canadian branch/transit numbers associated with a Yodlee account?

Tags: yodlee

We've successfully connected the Yodlee IAV API to our bank account and noticed that there is no way to identify the bank routing information.

We need these numbers to transfer funds to the user. You can take a look at: https://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification(IAV)_API/IAV_Services_Guide/API_References/IAV_REST_API_Reference/getItemVerificationData

You do get an account number but there are no branch/transit numbers associated with this account. I've talked to support and they said that they **do not** scrape this information off Canadian banks.

Are there any alternatives to getting this information?

Here is the info retrieved from Yodlee IAV:

```
[{
       "itemVerificationInfo": {
              "transactionId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
              "itemId": 1000003,
              "contentServiceId": 3736,
              "requestStatus": { "verificationRequestStatus": "SUCCEEDED" },
              "requestType": { "name": "IAV_FAST" },
              "requestTime": "2015-05-26T21:07:34-0700",
              "completionTime": "2015-05-26T21:08:03-0700",
              "completed": true,
              "statusCode": 0,
              "localeErrorMessage": "LOCALE_NOT_SUPPORTED",
              "requestedLocale": "en_US",
              "derivedLocale": "en_CA",
              "siteRefreshStatus": {
                      "siteRefreshStatusId": 5,
                      "siteRefreshStatus": "REFRESH_COMPLETED"
              }
       },
       "accountVerificationData": [{
              "accountType": { "name": "CHECKING" },
              "availableBalance": {
                      "amount": "9.99", 
                      "currencyCode": "CAD"
              },
              "itemVerificationInfo": {
                      "transactionId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                      "itemId": 1000003,
                      "contentServiceId": 3736,
                      "requestStatus": { "verificationRequestStatus": "SUCCEEDED" },
                      "requestType": { "name": "IAV_FAST" },
                      "requestTime": "2015-05-26T21:07:34-0700",
                      "completionTime": "2015-05-26T21:08:03-0700",
                      "completed": true,
                      "statusCode": 0,
                      "localeErrorMessage": "LOCALE_NOT_SUPPORTED",
                      "requestedLocale": "en_US",
                      "derivedLocale": "en_CA",
                      "siteRefreshStatus": {
                              "siteRefreshStatusId": 5,
                              "siteRefreshStatus": "REFRESH_COMPLETED"
                      }
              },
              "accountNumber":  "9.99", 
              "accountName": "TD UNLIMITED CHEQUING ACCOUNT",
              "accountHolder": { "fullName": "My ProfileView Details" },
              "itemAccountId": 1000003
       }]
}]
```

PayPal also uses Yodlee IAV but they're able to somehow get this bank code field in their results: "10202004". http://canada-banks-info.com/routing-numbers/toronto-dominion-bank-routing-numbers/10202-004/

The interesting thing here is that THIS IS NOT my branch. My account is registered under a different branch. So maybe there is some sort of a logic to get these numbers? Maybe they're hardcoded for each institution number?

Answer (score 0):

Since Yodlee does not support Canadian banks through their service, your best option is to back-end your own database, and use it to either validate users' input or to seed `select` options.

You can obtain Branch & Transit numbers for all (most?) Canadian banks [here](http://canada-banks-info.com/).

Comment: The thing is PayPal also uses Yodlee and they somehow can see the "Bank Code" field. How can they do it?

Comment: Yodlee says it doesn't work - why would you conclude that PayPal has some special exception? Most likely, they're doing something very similar to this answer.

Comment: PayPal doesn't ask the user to enter branch or transit number. However they do have a bank code which is a combination of those 2 numbers. Where do they get those numbers? I've updated my question with the returned IAV result.